# Sum of the equation in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Do help to solve these 2 questions

$\
{n \choose 0}^2 + {n \choose 1}^2 +{n \choose 2}^2 +...+{n \choose (n-1)/2  }^2= ? $ when n is odd

$\
{n \choose 0}^2 + {n \choose 1}^2 +{n \choose 2}^2 +...+{n \choose n }^2= ? $

$\
{n \choose 0}^2 + {n \choose 1}^2 +{n \choose 2}^2 +...+{n \choose n/2  }^2= ? $ when n is odd

Comment: use ${n \choose i}^2 = {n \choose i}{n \choose n-i}$

Comment: For the second one, you could consider the coefficient of $x^n$ on the LHS and RHS of $(1 + x)^{2n} = (1 + x)^n(1 + x)^n$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

For the second one, note that consider the binomial expansion of $(1 + x)^n$, then we can collect the terms of $x^n$ in $(1 + x)^n(1+x)^n$ to get:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i}\cdot\binom{n}{n - i} = \sum_{i = 1}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{i}=\sum_{i = 0}^n\binom{n}{i}^2$$

which is exactly what we need. On the other hand, $(1 + x)^n(1 + x)^n = (1 + x)^{2n}$ so the coefficient of $x^n$ on both sides should be equal. That is to say,

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n\binom{n}{i}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$$

For the first one, you could use the same trick, just collect a different term instead of $x^n$.